# Facebook login never callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, fbconnect

I've implemented FB login, but never getting callback...
In .plist I did add the FacebookAppID and FacebookDisplayName

Here is my code. Its the all relevant code from my question

```
-(IBAction)btnLoginWithFBClick:(id)sender {

    _session = [[FBSession sessionForApplication:kApiKey secret:kApiSecret delegate:self] retain];
    [_session resume];

    if (![_session isConnected]) {
        _loginDialog = nil;
        _loginDialog = [[FBLoginDialog alloc] init];
        _loginDialog.delegate = self;
        [_loginDialog show];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"logado");



- (void)dialogDidSucceed:(FBDialog *)dialog {
    if ([dialog isMemberOfClass:[FBLoginDialog class]]) {
        NSLog(@"[FBLoginDialog::dialogDidSucceed] just did succeed");
    } else if ([dialog isMemberOfClass:[FBPermissionDialog class]]) {
        NSLog(@"[FBPermissionDialog::dialogDidSucceed] update user status");
       // [self facebookUpdateUserStatus];
    }
}

- (void)session:(FBSession*)session didLogin:(FBUID)uid {
    [self getFacebookName];
    [_loginDialog setHidden:YES];
}

- (void)session:(FBSession*)session willLogout:(FBUID)uid {
    //_logoutButton.hidden = YES;
    _facebookName = nil;
}

- (void)getFacebookName {
    NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"select uid,name, email, sex, pic from user where uid == %lld", _session.uid];
    NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];
    [[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.fql.query" params:params];
}

- (void)dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    if (![[url absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"fbconnect://success#="]) { // your msg
        NSLog(@"ae");
  }
} 


- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result {

    if ([request.method isEqualToString:@"facebook.fql.query"]) {
        NSArray* users = result;
        NSDictionary* user = [users objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Usuario facebook: %@", user);
        NSString *identifier = [user objectForKey:@"uid"];
        NSString *name = [user objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *email = [user objectForKey:@"email"];
        NSString *sex = [user objectForKey:@"sex"];
     }
}
```

I have setted in Facebook application the Apple Id , Bundle id etc
I did looking for the solution on google but nothing works...Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use FBLoginView for facebook login add FBLoginView to your view.
Implement the FBLoginViewDelegate methods like.

```
-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

 //do what you want when login is successfull.

  }
```

//for logging off u can simply pop to the view on which you have added FBLoginview

//or u can call this method to log off and pop to view you want

```
- (void)closeSession {

    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

}
```

// also add this method to your appdelegate

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation{

        // FBSample logic
        // We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order 
        // for SSO authentication to work.

       return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];


    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i was missing the method in appdelegate, that worked spot on!